# Поиск и замена текста у вложенных элементов DOMи регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, dom, replace

Есть необходимость сделать JS скрипт реализующий тултипы к словам на различных сайтах с различной структурой DOM. Для этого я создал JSON базу с наборами искомых слов и соответственно выводимыми к ним в тултип параметрами. проблема в том, что искать и заменять нужно и подстроку типа "Модель 001 красная" и подстроку типа "001 красная". Вот тут начинается беда, так как любой способ обхода DOM делает следующее, он сперва находит и добавляет тэги тултипа к одной фразе, а потом в эти тэги всовывает матрёшкой еще такие же тэги так как находит второе вхождение.

Я знаю как перебрать все элементы вложенные в указанный тег, делаю это с помощью

```
$(myCollection+' *').each(function(i,e){
```

я даже могу получить текст из текущего элемента, без вложенных, у меня есть регулярка получающая текст между тегами не затрагивая параметры тэга, но мне всё это ничего не даёт. Я не могу добиться того, что бы заменив во фразе

```
"бла бла бла Модель 001 красная бла"
```

текст на

```
бла бла бла 
<span class='special_class' special_param='aaa'>
Модель 001 красная
<div class='div_special_class'>
Название: Модель 001 красная
</div>
</span> 
бла
```

цикл больше не пытался заменить в данном теге текст содержащийся теперь уже в моих добавленных тегах на что то еще.

Я так понимаю, что мою регулярку:

```
RegExp('(?!<.*?)\\b('+json[starMon_shipID]['ship_name'][shipNames]+')\\b(?![^<>]*?(</a>|>))', 'gi' )
```

нужно как то научить заменять текст не только исключая внешние тэги но и внутринние (я с помощью цикла и так доберусь до всех элементов DOM, мне не нужно заменять во всех вложенных с помощью регулярки). Как добиться того, что бы регулярка заменяла только текст ААА или ааААА без всего иного в нижестоящем примере? Для примера я использовал DIV, но теги могут быть любые содержащие текст

```
<div>bla bla ааAAA bla<div>bla BBB bla</div></div>
```

Comment: Вы же вроде бы уже согласились [вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460395/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b#comment502356_460395), что использовать регулярное выражения для этой задачи не самая хорошая идея. Или все-таки не согласились?)

Comment: Верно. Но сама заменя то должна быть произведена реплейсом. Кстати я вроде решил проблему только что. 1) пишу в тэг который добавляю исходное заменяемое значение "фразу", ид и полное название. 2) не добавляю вложенные теги на этой стадии. 3) после цикла замены прохожусь еще раз удаляя во всех тегах матрёшки 4) воссодаю оригинальную фразу взяв из парамтера тега 5) имея ид, название и оригинальную фразу уже потом добавляю всё что надо в качестве вложенных тегов тултипа

Comment: А что вам мешает рекурсивно обходить дерево DOM и производить замены только в листовых (текстовых) узлах?

Comment: Тобиш принцип таков. Сперва как бы пробегаюсь и помечаю что нужно тегом с особыми параметрами и пофиг что возникнут матрёшки. Потом удаляю все матрёшки. Потом собираю конструкцию имея все нужные данные из тегов которые использовал для пометки.

Comment: Это вы имеете в виду nodeType? я добавляю это так же в цикле для отсеивания лишних вариантов. Но всёравно уже внутри юзаю регулярку. Вероятно я что то недогоняю тогда, если можно было обратиться как то иначе?        var text = elem.html().replace(new RegExp('тут регулярка', 'gi' ), replacer);
       elem.html(text); я же никак не могу иначе заменить значение в elem и только в нём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь задача стала интереснее, вот такой код должен работать:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $targets = $('.target');
    var replace = /(replace.?me)/;
    var replacement = '<div class="found">$1</div>';
    $targets.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && this.textContent.match(replace)) { // найти все подходящие тектовые ноды
                var tempNode = document.createElement('div'); //временный элемент
                tempNode.innerHTML = this.textContent.replace(replace, replacement); //замена
                var $this = $(this); // запоминаем текущую текстноду
                $(tempNode).contents().each(function() { //все элемнты во временной
     $this.before(this); // поставить перед текущей текстнодой
                });
                $(this).remove(); //убрать текущую текстноду
            }
        });

    });
});
```

```css
div {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
.found {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.target {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.not-target {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some">
    <div class="target">text replaceme
        <div class="target">text
            <div class="target">replaceme notme</div>
            <div class="not-target">replaceme I not target</div>
            <div class="target">hello replaceme</div>replace me text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="some">
    <div class="target">text replaceme
        <div class="target">text
            <div class="target">replaceme notme</div>
            <div class="not-target">replaceme I not target</div>
            <div class="target">hello replaceme</div>replace me text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="some">
    <div class="target">text replaceme
        <div class="target">text
            <div class="target">replaceme notme</div>
            <div class="not-target">replaceme I not target</div>
            <div class="target">hello replaceme</div>replace me text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="some">
    <div class="target">text replaceme
        <div class="target">text
            <div class="target">replaceme notme</div>
            <div class="not-target">replaceme I not target</div>
            <div class="target">hello replaceme</div>replace me text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="some">
    <div class="target">text replaceme
        <div class="target">text
            <div class="target">replaceme notme</div>
            <div class="not-target">replaceme I not target</div>
            <div class="target">hello replaceme</div>replace me text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я уже как раз отладил свой вариант с регуляркой. Сейчас ради интереса попробую сравнить что будет сколько выполняться.

Comment: сколько не важно, важно,  что регуляркой вы врядли легко выберете скажем такой элемент: `'.target > .not-target + .target'`; http://jsfiddle.net/bhbL8nnd/

Comment: Вот чего мне не хватало - "textContent" !!! Вот о таком свойстве я не знал и без него то как раз и страдал.

Comment: Пробую, не работает в моем конкретном случае. Подозреваю, что var replace = /(replace.?me)/; косячит, я то его заменяю на var replace = /название_для_теста/gi;

Comment: ну так это для примера, пишите `var replace = new RegExp('тут регексп', gi)` или как там у вас было.

Comment: Да, всё получилось, у меня косяк был, забыл селектору * добавить что бы вышло var $targets = $('.selector_tag *'); И огогой! Еще и русскоязычные замены заработали, так как их моя сложная регулярка видать резала, а в JSON были варианты на русском в том числе.

Comment: Так. Еще есть беда. Не работает замена если искомая фраза состоит из 2 слов. Как я писал в первом посте бывает не просто "название", а "вот такое название" или "такое название". Видимо все же косяк в регулярке var replace = new RegExp(json[key], 'gi'); ?

Comment: наверное, выведете значение textNodes в консоль, как видите в моем тесте  слова с пробелом заменяются.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bhbL8nnd/1/

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, ошибка в генераторе JSON. Просто небыло данных верных. Еще раз извиняюсь, если отнял время! Спасибо! Все работает шикарно! И рус и англ варианты подстрок заменяются корректно.